# Where can I find a Husk Bully?

Tags: hollow-knight

According to a guide I found, the only Hunter's Journal entry I'm missing is the Husk Bully. Where can I find one of these? If it matters, my Forgotten Crossroads is infected.

Comment: I think after infection there is no Husk Bully in Crossroads. May be you can find them in Deepnest, I saw something like them where dead bodies turn to spiders.

Comment: @Exerion Those enemies are called Corpse Crawlers. They behave like normal Crossroad Husks (and iirc even count towards the Hunters journal entry for them) but when you kill them there is a chance for their corpse to start shuddering and spawn spider-like legs and crawl around the area.

Answer (score 2):

The [comments on the Hollow Knight wiki](http://hollowknight.wikia.com/wiki/Husk_Bully) show several locations (outside the Crossroads) where you can still find the Husk Bully once the Crossroads have been infected.

- In Greenpath:

  [image]
- In the City of Tears on the path to the Nailsmith.
- In the connecting area between the Ancient Basin and the City of Tears (right above the tram):

  [image]
- As Exerion mentioned in a comment, there also some in Deepnest.

You can distinguish Husk Bullies from Wandering Husks a) by their smaller heads and b) by their charging attack (Wandering Husks walk towards you much more slowly with their arms flailing).